# How to put sleep command in a tcl script?

Tags: tcl, sleep, expect

I'm trying to put a sleep command in a tcl script to wait 10 seconds before send the disconnect command:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set n 0

if { $argc != 1 } {
        puts "The script requires the number of bot."
        puts "Please try again."
        exit 1
    } else {
        set n [lindex $argv 0]
        }

# Spawn Python and await prompt
spawn mono --debug pCampBot.exe -loginuri http://127.0.0.1:9000 -s home -n $n -firstname test -lastname bot_ -password 123 -b p
expect "pCampbot#"

# Send Python statement and await prompt
send "conn\n"
expect "pCampbot#"

sleep 10

send "disconn\n"
expect "pCampbot#"

# Pass control to user so he can interact with Python
interact
```

The problem is that sleep command it's like it's executed after the spawn command, that is it waits 10 seconds and after send "conn" and "disconn" commands sequentially.

I don't know why it behaves like that and i don't know how i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl uses the `after` command for this, provided you give it a single argument that is an integer number of *milliseconds*. To sleep for 10 seconds, you do:

```
after 10000
```

Comment: Passing more arguments than one does something different, scheduling a command for later execution.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I tried to put "after" command instead of "sleep" but the behaviour that I found is the same. Putting the next "send" commands as the "after" parameters like that: after 10000 { send "\ndisconn\n" after 10000 { send "quit\n" } } it seems work well. I had to enter an extra escape character before "disconn\n" because, i don't know the reasons, but the script puts in the shell command line "020;17R", so i must first send away this symbols and after send the "disconn" command.